# Which is the best lossless database compression technique

Tags: database, compression

I have a database with millions of records in it.

the table has two attribute 1] Name 2] Location

there are many records which has different name but same location so is there any compression technique that can be applied on the location attribute?

You can suggest the various loss-less compression techniques with their supported database names.

Comment: How about just [normalizing your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: Why do you want to compress the data? Do you actually have a space problem or are you just trying to prematurely optimize for size? You should consider what happens if you succeed, how would you query the database for locations? In any case, would it be possible to have a location-table, and just store a reference instead? Presumably (but you'd have to check) a reference of type int would take less space in total if there's a lot of the locations being reused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Normalise your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Have a `LOCATIONS` table and give your first table a foreign key into it.

Less than 65,535 distinct locations? That's two bytes per record in your original table. Pretty good compression if you ask me. Also makes indexing and comparisons faster.

Data is more important than code. Get the data right first. **Normalise as much as possible by default**. Denormalise only after you've discovered a (specific, measured, and fully-attributed) performance problem or some great cause.

Comment: Will you please write the query to Normalize my DB

Comment: It's not a query, it's how you create the database in the first place. There will probably be a few queries involved in the migration, something like "INSERT INTO locations SELECT FROM ..." (I forget the exact syntax) followed by "UPDATE addresses SET location_id=(SELECT id FROM locations..." then remove the redundant old column.

Comment: @sam: You can always add a lat/lng pair to your table and use a spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a spatial index. A si reduces the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. A si is used in heatmaps and treemaps. It looks like a quadtree.

Comment: Ha ha first I thought you'd completely missed the point. Then I realised **I** had! Yeah if locations are strings like addresses then read my answer -- if locations are latitude/longitude or something, then you need to discretize your data.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but can you elaborate what you mean with discretize? Can you give me an example of a discrete function? Or is a spatial index a discrete function? I've a bad day.

Comment: Yes, it is. `x` and `y` may be continuous values but if you split the universe in half and say "(x1,y1) in the left, (x2,y2) in the right" then you have a 1-bit discrete value to distinguish the points. Other examples are [vector quantization](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3090/image_compression_with_vector_.php), octree addressing, etc. Relational databases don't handle this natively but they can store a BSP "path" as an ordinary integer.

Comment: Thank you. Nice article and with code. I've add it to my collection.